# How to access json variable which is inside script instead of using $.getJSON to get external json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Currently working with this highcharts code:
https://jsfiddle.net/umL154cd/
It works with external data source like shown below:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity) {
        $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) { ///
```

But I'd like to truncate the data and put it inside the code itself by simply anouncing json.variable:

```
var datafromjson =
{
    "xData": [0.001567,0.011765,0.022194],
    "datasets": [{
        "name": "Speed",
        "data": [13.833,12.524,11.441,10.651],
        "unit": "km/h",
        "type": "line",
        "valueDecimals": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Elevation",
        "data": [26.857,27,27.111,27.2,27.272],
        "unit": "m",
        "type": "area",
        "valueDecimals": 0
    }, {
        "name": "Heart rate",
        "data": [101,98,103],
        "unit": "bpm",
        "type": "area",
        "valueDecimals": 0
    }]
};
```

How do I replace `$.getJSON` request so the script will take the turncated in-script data insted of accessing external data?

Thank you!

Comment: Just put it in the script.  I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: I did, but then how do I apply the same functions and logic to the added json object?
In case I add datafromjson object it should be something like:

$.getJSON('datafromjson', function (activity) {

But that's not how $.getJSON method works. That's why the question. Thanx for the fast response anyway!

Comment: If you include the json in a variable in the script, there is no need to use $.getJSON at all.  Just use the variable for your $.each

Comment: Yes, thank you! I had to unwrap the code from $.getJSON, and then to rename my object from 'datafromjson' to 'activity'. In the following code
 `$.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) `

"activity" isn't just some functions argument but actually the name of json object.

If you'd like to create an answer I'd gladly mark it as a correct solution.